# Controlling the size of a function

Tags: analysis

Consider the function
$$f(\delta,r)=\frac{2e^{-\delta r} }{r}\sinh\left(r/2\right)$$
with $\delta >0$

Show that $\exists r >0 \text{ such that }f(\delta,r)<1$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
f(\delta,r)=e^{-\delta r}\cdot \left(\frac{e^{r/2}-e^{-r/2}}{r}\right)
\end{align*}
Take $\delta =0$, then 
$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}f(0,r)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{0.5e^{r/2}+0.5e^{-r/2}}{1}=1$$
by l'hopital's rule

In other words,
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \gamma >0 \text{ such that}, 0<r<\gamma \implies 1-\epsilon<f(0,r)<1+\epsilon$$

Clearly,$$f(\delta,r)=e^{-\delta r}f(0,r)$$
It follows that,
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \gamma >0 \text{ such that}, 0<r<\gamma \implies (1+\epsilon)e^{-\delta r}<f(\delta,r)<(1+\epsilon)e^{-\delta r}$$
I tried showing that $(1+\epsilon)e^{-\delta r}<1$ for $\epsilon$ small enough, however it did not work. The problem is that I cannot control freely $\epsilon$ and $r$ at the same time.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $g_\delta(r)=f(\delta,r)$ is a continuous function whose value at $r=0$ equals zero, so in a neighbourhood of the origin $|g_\delta(r)|<1$ has to hold. If $\delta>1$, that holds in a neighbourhood of $+\infty$, too.

Comment: Hi Jack, apologies the function was wrote incorrectly. It should be $\frac{2e^{-\delta r} }{r}\sinh\left(r/2\right)$

Comment: The same argument works with a minor fix. In that case $\lim_{r\to 0}g_\delta(r)=1$ and $g_{\delta}(r)$ is decreasing in a right neighbourhood of zero, since $\lim_{r\to 0}g_\delta'(r)=-\frac{\delta}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$ \frac{\sinh x}{x}\leq e^{x^2/6} $$
we have:
$$ f(\delta,r) \leq \exp\left(-\delta r+\frac{r^2}{24}\right) $$
so $0<f(\delta,r)<1$ for any $r\in(0,24\cdot\delta)$.